# How can I detect if my app is running on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-store-apps

This is a fairly common question, but I haven't seen an answer for Windows Store Apps, which generally don't have access to the full Win32 API. I'm currently building ARM and x86 versions. I don't care if the processor is 64-bit or not, or if the process is WoW64, or whatever (unless that answers the underlying question). Specifically, I want to know how many of my users would be able to run an x64 build.

**So, my question:** From an x86 XAML/C++ Windows Store App, how can I tell if the user is running the 64-bit version of the OS?

If that's not possible, is there a way to tell if the processor is 64-bit?

Comment: You can't call GetSystemInfo() from the Win32 API, that won't pass the Store validator. But try GetNativeSystemInfo(), it can.

Comment: `GNSI()` appears to work. Haven't run it through the WACK yet but will do in a few days.